# Can I override a Powershell native cmdlet but call it from my override

Tags: powershell

In Javascript it is possible to do so, I think. In Powershell I'm not sure how to :

Let's say I want to override every call to write-host with my custom method but at some time I want to execute the native write-host inside my overide. Is it possible to store the native implentation under another name so as to call it later from new implementation ?

Update : it seems to me that the answer https://serverfault.com/a/642299/236470 does not fully answer the second part of my question. How do I store and call the native implementation ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Calls to functions will override cmdlets. You can read more on this from [about_Command_Precedence on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx) ...

> If you do not specify a path, Windows PowerShell uses the following
>        precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Function
> 3. Cmdlet
> 4. Native Windows commands

So simply making a function of the same name as a native cmdlet will get you what you want.

```
function Write-Host{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        $string
    )
    Process {
        # Executes once for each pipeline object
        If ($string -match "bagels"){
            Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host $string -ForegroundColor Green
        }else{
            Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host $string
        }
    }
}
```

So now `write-host` works with pipeline input that we can filter with. Calling the "real" cmdlet is as easy as specifying the module in the call. You can see I have done that twice in the above code sample. Some sample usage and output would be the following:

[image]

Be careful that you don't forget you have done this if you save it in a profile or something of that nature. Use `Get-Command Write-Host` whenever in doubt. In my case you can remove the override by calling `Remove-Item function:write-host`

You can also look into what are called proxy functions but I think that is overkill for what you intend to do.

Comment: ah, beat me by seconds. Let me know if you think mine is too similar, I'll just delete it.

Comment: @briantist It's fine. It connects the SF answer to here and vice versa (which is good). I tried finding a dupe of this and had a hard time.

Comment: <3 Matt and briantist :-p

Comment: @Matt it seems to me that the answer does not fully answer the second part of my question. How do I store and call the native implementation ?

Comment: @user310291 Unless I misinterpreted the question I did answer that already. You can call the native implementation by prefacing it with its module name. It is what I did inside my example function. You dont need to _store_ it. It is always there.

Comment: Note: `$_` only works when pipelining, so if you call it like `Write-Host "anything"` the function doesn't work at all

Comment: @DineiRockenbach Yes that is true. Covering all nuances of how this should be implemented was not supposed to be the scope of the answer.

Comment: @Matt even so, it's very confusing to copy-paste this implementation and not realize why it doesn't work for this simple scenario. Perhaps add a comment in the answer? Or if you really feel generous add some simple implementation that would work for `Write-Host "anything"`...

Comment: Thanks! Made a small correction, hope I didn't mess anything up (I was assuming it was unintentional for `write-host "bagels"` and `"bagels" | write-host` to behave differently).

Comment: @OhadSchneider Ah yes. Nice catch. Thanks. Late night coding again for me and I missed something.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can. [I have an answer for that here on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/642299/236470), but since it's a different site I'll copy it since I can't close as duplicate to another site.

---

Yes, you can override `Get-ChildItem` or any other cmdlet in Powershell.

> ### Name Your Function The Same
>
> If you make a function with the same name in the same scope, yours will be used.
>
> Example:
>
> ```powershell
> Function Get-ChildItem {
> [CmdletBinding()]
> param(
>     # Simulate the parameters here
> )
>     # ... do stuff
> }
> ```
>
> ### Using Aliases
>
> Create your own function, and then create an alias to that function, with the same name as the cmdlet you want to override.
>
> Example:
>
> ```powershell
> Function My-GetChildItem {
> [CmdletBinding()]
> param(
>     # Simulate the parameters here
> )
>     # ... do stuff
> }
>
> New-Alias -Name 'Get-ChildItem' -Value 'My-GetChildItem' -Scope Global
> ```
>
> This way is nice because it's easier to test your function without
> stomping on the built-in function, and you can control when the cmdlet
> is overridden or not within your code.
>
> To remove the alias:
>
> ```powershell
> Remove-Item 'Alias:\Get-ChildItem' -Force
> ```

Comment: A suggestion I offer for the SF answer is to link to about_Command_Precedence as it explains why it works

Comment: Jackpot I helped you for once :)

Comment: @briantist it seems to me that the answer http://serverfault.com/a/642299/236470 does not fully answer the second part of my question. How do I store and call the native implementation ?

Comment: @user310291 I think that you're correct actually; you should accept Matt's answer as he fully explains how to call the native version.