# Hyper-V Powershell checkpoint creation/deletion is not synchronous. Is there a better option?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I've found myself having to write wrappers around powershell's [Remove-VMSnapshot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/hyper-v/remove-vmsnapshot?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Checkpoint-VM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/hyper-v/checkpoint-vm). The docs make no mention of it, but based on the Write-Host in both of the code snippets below executing, checkpoints are not fully deleted/created after the MS provided cmdlets. I hit this when trying to restore to a checkpoint by name immediately after creating it yielded an error.

Has anyone else encountered this? Thoughts on better ways to handle it? Tricks to prevent any of my code from calling the MS cmdlets directly?

```
function Remove-VMSnapshots-Sync
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][object]$VM,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$CheckpointName,
    )
    $matchingSnapshots = @(Get-VMSnapshot $VM | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $CheckpointName})
    $matchingSnapshots | Remove-VMSnapshot
    do
    {
        $matchingSnapshots = @(Get-VMSnapshot $VM | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $CheckpointName})
        $stillThere = $matchingSnapshots.length -gt 0
        if ($stillThere)
        {
            Write-Host 'sleeping to try to let snapshot disappear'
            start-sleep -s 1
        }
    } while ($stillThere)
}

function Checkpoint-VM-Sync
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][object]$VM,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$CheckpointName
    )
    $checkpoint = Checkpoint-VM -VM $VM -SnapshotName $CheckpointName -PassThru
    $checkpoint | Write-Host
    while (-not (@(Get-VMSnapshot $VM | Select -ExpandProperty Id)).Contains($checkpoint.Id))
    {
        Write-Host 'waiting for checkpoint to be in list'
        Get-VMSnapshot $VM | Write-Host
        start-sleep -s 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue, see the answer in [Can I override a Powershell native cmdlet ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override) it shows you how easily it is to override commands.

You need to add it into your profile (only for you), or add it to the script (for every one that runs the script), it depends on your situation.

Comment: Awesome, this will stop me from calling the unsafe async versions. :-)