# Powershell Write-Error Write-Warning custom format

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to specify a custom format for `Write-Error` and `Write-Warning` functions?

To match a specific format : "[ERROR] ... error text ..."

Example with Write-Warning:

Default:

`Write-Warning 'a message'` => `WARNING: a  message`

Custom format :

`Write-Warning 'a message'` => `[WARNING]: a  message`

Comment: you could parse the output and replace the text - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override#33747535

Answer (score 0):

You could give `PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml` a try. The file is located under `$PSHOME`. Grep the file for e.g. `NativeCommandErrorMessage` and see if you can adapt it.

Another way might be stream [redirection](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/). You could redirect the warning and error stream to the output stream, and (hopefully) filter warning and error out of it.

Hope that helps.