# Change Powershell Help System from Command More to Less

Tags: powershell

In powershell, the command "man" or "help" opens the Windows Powershell Help System. Unfortunately for every command that I run help on it opens the program "more", which I dislike. I have the process less available and would like to change the viewer to that text editor process. How can I bootup less instead of more instead of doing "help get-variable | less".

Comment: Simply override the Help command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override

Answer (score 2):

To change the pager `more` that is used with commands `man` and `help` you can do the following. Note: `Get-Help` does not invoke the pager `more` and therefore does not apply.

With Powershell 5.1 you can override more by setting an alias like so:

```
Set-Alias more less.exe
```

Starting with [Powershell Core 6+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-7#support-for-macos-and-linux) you can set variable $env:PAGER to override:

```
$env:PAGER = 'less.exe'
```

*Note: you'll need to specify the full path to less.exe if it's not in your PATH. Check with `Get-Command less.exe`*

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, in Powershell 6, you can set $env:PAGER to 'less'.

Answer (score -1):

By default, `man` is an alias for `help`, and `help` is a wrapper function around the `Get-Help` cmdlet, which pipes the output of `Get-Help` to `more`. To accomplish your aim, you will need to rewrite the `help` function to use `less` instead of `more`.