# How to replace a powershell function and call the old version?

Tags: powershell, memoization

I am trying to replace a powershell function and with a new one and then call the oldone from withing, but I am having little luck.

In my usecase I want to add caching to some webrequests. So i've added the following functions

```
$global:useCache = $true
$oldInvoke = ${function:Invoke-RestMethod}

function Remove-CachedRequests {
    $cachePath = "C:\tmp\Cache"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $cachePath -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
}

function Invoke-RestMethod {
    Param($Uri, $Method, $Headers)
    if ($global:useCache) {
        return _InvokeWithCache $Uri $Method $Headers
    }
    return _InvokeWithoutCache $Uri $Method $Headers
}

function GetFilename {
    Param($Uri, $Method, $Headers)
    $md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $bytes = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Uri + $Method + $Header)
    return [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($bytes))
}

function _InvokeWithoutCache {
    Param($Uri, $Method, $Headers)
    return $oldInvoke.Invoke(@{"Uri" = $url; "Method" = $Method; "Headers" = $Headers})
}

function _InvokeWithCache {
    Param($Uri, $Method, $Headers)
    $cachePath = "C:\tmp\Cache"
    $filename = GetFilename $Uri $Method $Headers
    $cache = Get-ChildItem -Filter $filename -Path $cachePath
    if ($cache.Length -gt 0) {
        return Import-Clixml $cache[0]
    }
    $res = _InvokeWithoutCache $Uri $Method $Headers
    $res | Export-Clixml "${cachePath}\${filename}"
    return $res
}
```

However, when `$oldInvoke.Invoke` is executed, it calls the new version instead of the old.
Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: If you over-ride a built-in cmdlet you can call the original by prefixing the call with the module name, as mentioned here: [Can I override a Powershell native cmdlet but call it from my override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I override a Powershell native cmdlet but call it from my override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override)

Comment: If you're looking to call the original `Invoke-RestMethod` _cmdlet_, then the linked answer should solve your problem. Note that unless you've previously defined a custom `Invoke-RestMethod` _function_, `${function:Invoke-RestMethod}` will evaluate to `$null`